# isValid Form vaildation then run a function AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms, validation

Just wondering if someone can please give me some pointers regarding running a function if an AngularJS form is Valid.

If the form is not valid then the errors appear but if the form is valid after clicking a submit button I would like it to move to the next step in the form (multistep form), so basically click of a button to validate, if valid it opens a new tab or an expandable etc.

Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

you can try disabling the button if form is invalid like

```
<button (click)="submit()" [disabled]="!contactForm.form.valid" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

where form tag looks like

```
<form #contactForm="ngForm"> ...
```

or if you want to not disable the button and check valid from code maybe like

```
<button (click)="submit($event, contactForm)" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

and on submit function

```
submit(event:any, contactForm:NgForm): void {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (contactForm.form.valid) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do like this:

html:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <div id="step1">
        <button type="button" ng-click="nextStep(form, validateStepOne, 2)">Next step</button>
    </div>
    <div id="step2">...</div>
    <div id="step3">...</div>
</form>
```

js:

```
function validateStepOne() {
    // validate form one and return true or false
}

function nextStep(form, validation, nextStepIndex) {
    if(form.$valid && validation()) {
        // go to next step
    }
}
```